# Adding Project reference programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, assemblies, runtime

Basically, after read a couple links, i tried the above code:

```
foreach (EnvDTE.Project proj in soln.Projects)
        {
            if (proj.Name == "BLL")
            {
                VSLangProj.VSProject vsproj = (VSLangProj.VSProject)proj.Object;                    
                vsproj.References.Add(@"C:\Teste\DAL\bin\Debug\DAL.dll");                    
            }
        }
```

All paths, project names, are hard-coded on purpouse, since im still testing how to achieve it.

Though it would act like if i did 
Project folder -> References -> Add reference -> Pick one, manually (compile time)

but after loading the solution, BLL project didnt contain any PERMANENT reference to DAL project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you forget to save modified  project , you have to invoke Save at the end

Comment: user592 or whatever your name is, you were right. I had to save the project, but i though you were talking about save the SOLUTION. Worked like a charm. Thanks :)