# Visual Studio 2013 IWizard ProjectFinishedGenerating How To Add A Reference Programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a small project of mine that requires using the IWizard interface from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard. I want to add a C# .NET reference to the project after it's generated based on input from a form. The project that's being generated is a C# library with custom code. All I need help in figuring out is how to access the references from the Project class. I've tried casting to a VSProject to no avial, and the documentation in the Remarks portion is fairly vague about it.

This is what it says in the documentation that I'm having trouble with:
"Reference this object by using DTE.Solution.Item or by using a specific language's objects, such as DTE.VBProjects.Item, or DTE.VCProjects.Item."
From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.project.aspx

Here's my code:

```
    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
    {
        VSProject vsproj = (VSProject)project;
        vsproj.References.Add(form.ReferenceDllPath);
    }
```

I've tried using the DTE as described, (VSProject)project.DTE.Solution.Items(0), but I've gotten errors. The above was my last resort. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try the code in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820763/adding-project-reference-programatically) post, it casts from the Object property `(VSProject)project.Object`;

Comment: That was it, thank you! Can I ask why I had to use .Object? I'm fairly new to C#, I'm coming over from Java.

Comment: I don't know... VS automation is not well documented, Google/SO is your best bet.